# Run Python code even after the IDE (Spyder) gets closed?

Tags: python

I have python scripts that are to be run exclusively in Spyder Environment [Windows OS]. Consider if someone accidentally closes the Spyder IDE, is it possible to run a piece of python code just before closing the environment? 
i.e, run a function only if the IDE is closed else do not run the function

Comment: If you are working on Linux, you could have a python script listenting on the status of Spyder's PID and have it execute your function when the PID dies. Would that make it?

Comment: @PabloM I should I have mentioned it earlier, that I am on Windows Environment